# Regex to Match only integer

Tags: c#, regex

As title says, I am trying to build a regex to extract integer number from a string. The actual scenario is, I am having a very large file of codes (the integers) and some values (decimals).

I can successfully extract the decimals with `[\d]*([.,][\d]*)`. (It may seem strange but I am also capturing .1 or 1.). However I cannot extract the integers, until now I have something like `[\d]*([\d]*)[\d]`. I also tried something like `^[\d]+$` but with no luck.

I will use this regex in a C# application, so I do not know if any additional 'rules' apply.

```
Regex ex = new Regex(@"MY_REGEX", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This is possibly a duplicate, however I cannot figure it out.

Having the

```
0066 435sxxzx 23454 2 3 45 06 11.3243 sds435 adc234wer
```

I am trying to match only

```
0066 23454 2 3 45 06
```

Here is an example in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mL1nU5/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure there are no decimal separators on both ends with lookarounds:

```
\b(?<!\.)\d+(?!\.)\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb(%3F%3C!%5C.)%5Cd%2B(%3F!%5C.)%5Cb&i=0066%20435sxxzx%2023454%202%203%2045%2006%2011.3243%20sds435%20)

C# (you do not seem to need the ignore case flag as `.` and digits do not have case variants):

```
var ex = new Regex(@"\b(?<!\.)\d+(?!\.)\b", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
```

The regex breakdown:

- `\b` - word boundary (we require the character before the number to be a non-word char or the beginning of a string
- `(?<!\.)` - this char cannot be a dot
- `\d+` - match 1+ digits...
- `(?!\.)` - only if not followed with a `.`
- `\b` - but there must be a non-word char or the end of string.

[image]

Comment: You regexes are very fragile: `[\d]*([.,][\d]*)` matches `.` and `,` because the `\d*` pattern can match ZERO or more digits. The second one is even more strange: `[\d]*([\d]*)[\d]` matches 0+ digits followed with 0+ digits  followed with 1 digits (so, it is basically `\d+`). The third one `^[\d]+$` is just matching strings that only contain 1 or more digits.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both the answer and the explanation. I will also keep in mind your comment in order to `fix` my other regular expressions. Out of curiosity, is it possible to achieve the same result without using `lookahead` and `lookbehind` ?

Comment: If there is no lookahead and lookbehind in the above code it will match the decimal also

Comment: @Akash: Right, that is why the lookarounds are there.

Answer (score 2):

This was too long for a comment, but just a suggestion: if the goal is obtaining the integer values themselves, rather than the text, you could use int.TryParse on each 'word' instead of regex. In a linq format:

```
string input = "0066 435sxxzx 23454 2 3 45 06 11.3243 sds435 adc234wer";

var ints = input.Split(' ')
    .Select(s=> {int i; if(int.TryParse(s,out i))return i; else return (int?)null;})
    .Where(i=>i.HasValue)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Here I am presenting a minimal example, where maybe split is the best way to go. However this does not apply to my actual code. Check also my comment in balint.steinbach answer.

Answer (score 1):

split the string by spaces.

For example in java:

```
String parts[] = text.split(" ");
```

Than you can check every word if it is a number with regex or by parsing it as a number.

Comment: While this will work in my example, It will not in my actual case. Operators and parenthesis can also indicate the start or end of word. In addition, another requirement that I have not mentioned is that I need to replace the `matches`. So using `reqex` is the best way to go.