# How can I find only integers with a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

Given the following string:

```
11 bsszzz 0.5 te 11.43 432 -66 a x
```

I want to find all the integers. In this case: `11`, `432` and `-66`

Which regular expression can I use for this?

I tried `-?\d+`, but it will return every number, including the ones that are part of decimal numbers.

**Edit:**

None of the following duplicate targets answers the question:

1. The solution in the duplicate target, [Regex to Match only integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35912778/10819573) gives `11`, `432`, and `66` which does not meet the requirement.
2. The solution in the duplicate target, [Python regex to match integers but not floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28030520/10819573) too gives the same output i.e. `11`, `432`, and `66`.

In fact, both the duplicate targets are duplicate of each other but none of them fulfils the requirement of this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `-?\\b(?<!\\.)\\d+(?!\\.)\\b` where

1. `-?` specifies optional `-`
2. `\b` specifies word boundary
3. `?<!` specifies [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and `?!` specifies negative lookahead.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="11 bsszzz 0.5 te 11.43 432 -66 a x";
        System.out.println(Pattern.compile("-?\\b(?<!\\.)\\d+(?!\\.)\\b")
                .matcher(str)
                .results()
                .map(MatchResult::group)                
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[11, 432, -66]
```

Comment: `-?\\b(?<!\\.)\\d+(?!\\.)\\b` is wrong, it won't find an interger value `20` in, say, `Nr.20`.

Comment: @RyszardCzech - There is no problem with the regex and it fulfils the requirement perfectly. The value, `20` in `Nr.20` does not qualify for the requirement. Do not misguide the visitors with a negative comment without asking the OP the relevant question. And, do that below the question, not below someone's answer. There were some comments below the question which are no more there. I trust the moderators who might have removed them for some purpose (the most common reason is a conflict or some hostile messages).

Comment: The title is "How can I find only integers with a regular expression?" - `-?\\b(?<!\\.)\\d+(?!\\.)\\b` does not find all only integers. See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/ZKbCXQ/1).

Comment: @RyszardCzech what is the point of your comment if this regex solved my problem? Why are you adding new conditions that I don't need?

Comment: @RyszardCzech   `Nr.20` could be taken to be either` Nr.` followed by`20` or `Nr` followed by `.20`. In the latter case it is clearly a decimal. But using your logic, the expression wouldn't find 2213 correctly because that is really 22 followed by 13 which is two integers back to back. So one needs to consider the OPs example in resolving this.